# The MAC signature found in the HTTP request is not the same as the computed signature. Server used following string to sign. Cosmos db with Mongo Api

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I am having issues doing a Post call to CosmosDb with the Mongo API. I created a container with the database, and when I run the postman get request: https://localhost:7014/api/Accounts

it works as expected.

When I try to make a post request however, I get the following error:
MongoDB.Driver.MongoWriteException: A write operation resulted in an error. WriteError: { Category : "Uncategorized", Code : 13, Message : "Error=13, Details='Response status code does not indicate success: Unauthorized (401); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: 1d489d66-490a-4d3e-84db-dd36ba9061fd; Reason: (Message: {"Errors":["The MAC signature found in the HTTP request is not the same as the computed signature. Server used following string to sign - 'post\ndocs\ndbs/IdentCrosswalkDB/colls/CrosswalkColl\nthu, 17 mar 2022 16:14:08 gmt\n\n'. Learn more: https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-tsg-mac-signature"]}

```
AccountsController.cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/Accounts")]
public class AccountsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly AccountsService _accountsService;

    public AccountsController(AccountsService accountsService) =>
        _accountsService = accountsService;

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<List<Account>> Get() =>
        await _accountsService.GetAsync();

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(Account newAccount)
    {
        await _accountsService.CreateAsync(newAccount);
        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Get), new { id =  newAccount.Id }, newAccount);
    }
```

```
AccountService.cs

using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoApi.Models;

namespace MongoApi.Services;

public class AccountsService
{
private readonly IMongoCollection<Account> _accountsCollection;

    public AccountsService(
        IOptions<AccountsDatabaseSettings> accountsDatabaseSettings)
    {
        var mongoClient = new MongoClient(
            accountsDatabaseSettings.Value.ConnectionString);

        var mongoDatabase = mongoClient.GetDatabase(
            accountsDatabaseSettings.Value.DatabaseName);

        _accountsCollection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<Account>(
            accountsDatabaseSettings.Value.AccountsCollectionName);
    }
    public async Task<List<Account>> GetAsync() =>
        await _accountsCollection.Find(_ => true).ToListAsync();

    public async Task CreateAsync(Account newAccount) {
        await _accountsCollection.InsertOneAsync(newAccount);
    }
}
```

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

namespace MongoApi.Models;
public class Account
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public string? Id { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("MGMId")]
    public string MGMId { get; set; } = null!;
    
    public long gseid { get; set; } = 0!;
    [BsonElement("MlifeId")]
    public long MlifeId { get; set; } = 0!;  
    public Object Profile {get;set;} = null!;
}
```

```
namespace MongoApi.Models;

public class AccountsDatabaseSettings
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; } = null!;

    public string DatabaseName { get; set; } = null!;

    public string AccountsCollectionName { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Comment: I often find this is caused when the clock on the client machine is not synchronized with the service. Can you try doing a sync on your machine's clock and retrying?

Comment: It appears that my machine's clock is synced.

Comment: Try taking the connection string and connect via mongoshell to confirm you can connect.

Comment: I did. i was able to connect with the connection string

Comment: Did you try the steps in the error message?  https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-tsg-mac-signature"

Comment: I did. At first I thought it might be the read-write key but it's still the same error. I haven't regenerated the key because it was the original I just created

Comment: interesting, i have the same problem. anyone find a fix?